# Combine table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabular

I would like to create table, which should look like this:

```
SortOrder1    SortOrder2    SortOrder3    SortOrder4

Item11       Item12         Item13
Item21       Item22         Item23
Item31       Item32         Item33

        <Pagination row>
```

Where

- Itemxx contains image and text.
- SortOrderx defines sort order. Logic of this sorting order on server part.
- Pagination row contains [1 2 .. last] elements , logic of which is on server part too ..

*Another description (to make it clearer to understand what I need)*:

I have a table which have composite items. E.g. table is 3x3 elements which contains images with subscription. Table's header contains 4 types of sorting (by name, by url, by price, etc).

I want to use jQuery but can't find a way..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "can't find a way?"

if you having issues wit h jquery  you can add this to your page

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Check out [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) they got plenty of [examples](http://datatables.net/examples/)

This plugin got **every thing** that you are looking for...

Here is a zero configuration example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

And some other examples :

[DataTables table sorting example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

[DataTables server-side processing example](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/)

Comment: you mean an external button that by clicking on it table will be sorted based on hidden column?

Comment: I have a table which have composite items. E.g. table is 3x3 elements which contains images with subscription. Table's header contains 4 types of sorting (by name, by url, by price, etc)

Comment: are you using any jquery plugin to generate the table ? or its just an simple html table?

Comment: currently i'm using html to generate table/data

Comment: sorry thought you are looking for a jquery plugin for table... anyway INMO the datatables plugin is much easier to work with that with jstl...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{     
    $('#example').dataTable( {         
        "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]     
    } ); 
} );
```

Demo from this site

> http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html